# How can I output something$! using Velocity 2.3?

Tags: escaping, velocity

I'm using Velocity to generate code for Angular 12, what I need is like:

`something$! : Observable<string>;`

but $! is very special in Velocity, I tried the followings with no luck:

- `something$!` => `something$`
- `something\$\!` => `something\$`
- `something$\!` => `something$`

I find no clue in [Advanced Issues: Escaping and !](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/user-guide.html#advanced-issues-escaping-and)

Comment: I find out a workaround:


    #set($dollar='$')
    something$dollar! : Observable<string>;

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions. Here are three:

1. Insert an empty comment between the dollar and the exclamation point:

```
something$#**#! : Observable<string>;
```

2. Mark the line or part of it as non parsed:

```
#[[
something$! : Observable<string>;
]]#
```

3. Define a Velocity variable

```
#set( $dollarbang = '$!') ## be sure to use single quotes
something$dollarbang : Observable<string>;
```